# Prove that $(1+a_1) \cdot (1+a_2) \cdot \dots \cdot (1+a_n) \geq 2^n$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

Let $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $a_1\cdot a_2\cdots a_n=1$, , prove that $(1+a_1) \cdot (1+a_2) \cdot \dots \cdot (1+a_n) \geq 2^n$
I have tried factorising but it just lead me to extremily complicated equation that were extremily difficult to understand... Could someone help me?

Comment: $1+a\ge 2\sqrt{a}$ for $a\ge 0$.

Comment: And....? I don't see why that would help...

Comment: Thus $LHS\ge 2^n\sqrt{a_1\cdot a_2 \cdots a_n}$

Comment: Could you please detail how you got there?

Comment: You replace $a$ by $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$ and time them up

Answer (score 4):

applying the AM-GM inequality n-times we get
$$(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\cdot...\cdot(1+a_n)\geq 2^n\sqrt{a_1a_2\cdot...\cdot a_n}=2^n$$ since $$a_1a_2\cdot...\cdot a_n=1$$

Answer (score 3):

> We will use **basic** AM-GM inequality to solve this problem.

### Proof of the basic form

$$(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2 \ge 0 \implies a + b -2\sqrt{ab} \ge 0 \implies {a+b\over2} \ge \sqrt{ab}$$

[General proof here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean/#proof-of-am-gm-inequality)

---

### Your question

$${1+a_1\over 2} \ge \sqrt{a_1} \implies \color{red}{1 + a_1} \ge \color{blue}{2\sqrt{a_1}}$$
$${1+a_2\over 2} \ge \sqrt{a_2} \implies \color{red}{1 + a_2} \ge \color{blue}{2\sqrt{a_2}}$$
$${1+a_3\over 2} \ge \sqrt{a_3} \implies \color{red}{1 + a_3} \ge \color{blue}{2\sqrt{a_3}}$$

$$\vdots$$

$${1+a_n\over 2} \ge \sqrt{a_n} \implies \color{red}{1 + a_n} \ge \color{blue}{2\sqrt{a_n}}$$

Multiplying all the red things together, $\color{red}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)(1+a_3) \cdots (1+a_n)}$ .

And the blue things, $\color{blue}{(2\sqrt{a_1})(2\sqrt{a_2})(2\sqrt{a_3}) \cdots (2\sqrt{a_n})}= \color{blue}{2^n\sqrt{a_1a_2a_3\cdots a_n}} \leftarrow \text{(why ?)}$

Combing it all together we get,

$$\color{green}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\cdot...\cdot(1+a_n)\geq 2^n\sqrt{a_1a_2\cdot...\cdot a_n}}$$

$$\color{green}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\cdot...\cdot(1+a_n)\geq 2^n} \leftarrow \text{(why ?)}$$
$$\color{red}{\star}\color{green}{\star}\color{blue}{\star}\color{yellow}{\star}\color{indigo}{\star}\color{red}{\star}\color{green}{\star}\color{blue}{\star}\color{yellow}{\star}\color{indigo}{\star}\color{red}{\star}\color{green}{\star}\color{blue}{\star}\color{yellow}{\star}\color{indigo}{\star}\color{red}{\star}\color{green}{\star}\color{blue}{\star}\color{yellow}{\star}\color{indigo}{\star}$$
And we are done. If still something isn't clear please ask me.

---

[Not very beginner friendly but certainly a good read on inequalities](http://www.aam.org.in/site/st_material/14.pdf)

Comment: Nice answer, +1. I'd recommend you to read the meta questions about using many colors in answers, I believe most people here won't like them.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Why ?  Sorry i did not know that. Thanks for telling me. Should i change everything to black ?

Comment: Well, it's mostly a problem for color-blind people, I believe (though not sure, I don't remember exactly what I read in those questions), that green-blue combinations were hard for people with that disability to differentiate. I wouldn't change it, just have that in mind.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD thanks, i will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

See [HUYGEN’S INEQUALITY](https://mathematicaldreams.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/work-013/). It's a more general result.

[image]

Comment: Any reasons for down voting?

Comment: I can come up with reasons for downvotes but I find it a helpful pointer (+1 from me).

Answer (score 0):

It's also Holder inequality for $n$ sequences.