# Is there a relationship between $a_1\cdot a_2\cdot\dots\cdot a_n$ and $(a_1+1)\cdot(a_2+1)\cdot\dots\cdot(a_n+1)$?

Tags: inequality

I want to find an inequality between the to terms... Assuming all the $a_i $ to be positive, the one where $1$ is added to all the $a_i$ is bigger, but is there a real relationship? It doesn't have to be an inequality because I need something stronger than that...

Comment: Ohh no... So yea I am researching an relationship...

Comment: Do you want a lower bound for the latter term in terms of the former or something like that?

Comment: I would realy like a formula for the RHS ... That would help me so much

Comment: Is there a part of this problem you're not telling us? Earlier today these exact products came up with the additional information that  the $a_i$ are positive, $a_1a_2\cdots a_n=1$ and we were asked to show that $(a_1+1)\cdots(a_n+1)\geq 2^n$. Is that what your problem is as well?

Comment: Yes it is in depth, but I didn't understand the solution and wanted something more specific...

Comment: The solution is simple: $(a_i+1)\geq 2\sqrt{a_i}$, so $(a_1+1)\cdots(a_n+1)\geq 2^n\sqrt{a_1\cdots a_n}=2^n$, as was written in the answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1911849/let-a-1-a-2-dots-a-n-in-mathbbr-and-a-1-cdot-a-2-cdot-dots-cdot-a). If there is something specific you didn't understand, please ask about that instead. Write a comment to that answer asking for clarification, whatever. Asking a new question without context, and without asking about what you're really wondering about is bad.

Comment: @TheodoreAlberter check my answer on your original question, may clear  some of your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example should indicate a general pattern:

$${(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)\over2^3}={1+a+b+c+ab+bc+ca+abc\over8}\ge\sqrt[8]{1\cdot a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot ab\cdot bc\cdot ca\cdot abc}=\sqrt[8]{a^4b^4c^4}=\sqrt{abc}$$

The key step is the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean inequality.

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to prove that $(1+a_1)\cdot\dots\cdot(1+a_n)$ has, when decomposed, $2_n$ terms? Please...

Comment: @TheodoreAlberter, you can prove it by induction on $n$:  If $(1+a_1)\cdots(1+a_{n-1})$ expands out to $2^{n-1}$ terms, then, when multiplied by $(1+a_n)$, there will be $2^{n-1}$ terms with an $a_n$ and $2^{n-1}$ terms without, for a total of $2\cdot2^{n-1}=2^n$ terms in all.